# Did Rav Saadiah Gaon really phrase the bracha as "Sim shalom b'olam . . ."?

Tags: sources-mekorot, prayer-book, nuschaot, saadya-gaon

In *Or Hadash*, the commentary on *Siddur Sim Shalom* (the American Conservative siddur), it states that the nineteenth bracha of the Amidah was intentionally reworded from the the standard

> ...שׂים שׁלום ,טובה וּברכה

to

> ...שׂים שׁלום בעלם ,טובה וּברכה

the "Grant peace" becoming "Grant universal peace".  The commentary sites the Siddur of Rav Saadiah Gaon as the precedent for this change.  I tried to find evidence of that phrasing in [*Siddur Rav Saadiah Gaon*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) from http://hebrewbooks.org .  On [page 78 of the pdf file,](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_20685_78.pdf) I found that bracha, but in the conventional "Sim shalom" form without the "b'olam".

What am I missing here?  Is it just this printing of Rav Saadiah's Siddur that phrases it the conventional way?  Both Rabbi Jules Harlow and Rabbi Reuven Hammer have written that the "b'olam" phrasing was lifted from this source.  I don't think they made that fact up.  Where did they get the idea that was written by Rav Saadiah that way?  Is there a different text found (maybe from the Cairo Geniza) that is not the same as the published version of this siddur that is linked above?

Comment: Now I wonder about the propriety of inserting the word in the earlier phrase and why it wouldn't be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Saadya Gaon's Siddur, the phrase shows up again with the desired variation at the end of the blessing and seems to have been transplanted from there to the beginning of the blessing in *Siddur Sim Shalom*. Here is the full text of the blessing from your linked-to pdf (emphasis added):

> שים שלום טובה וברכה חן וחסד ורחמים וברכנו כלנו כאחד במאור פניך כי ממאור פניך נתתה לנו ייי אלהינו תורה וחיים אהבה וחסד צדקה ורחמים וטוב בעיניך לברך עמך ישראל בכל עת **שים שלום בעולם** ועל עמך ישראל יהי נא שלום מעתה ועד עולם ברוך אתה ייי המברך את עמו ישראל בשלום.