# Understanding the end of the Blessing 'Sim Shalom'

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

In the sentence

> כי באור פניך נתת לנו ה' אלוהינו תורת חיים ואהבת חסד וצדקה וברכה
>   ורחמים וחיים ושלום

are the words

> אהבת חסד וצדקה וברכה ורחמים וחיים ושלום

attributes of the Torah, or are they independent things?

Answer (score 2):

The Art Scroll Siddur and the Koren Siddur by Rabbi Jonathan Sacks (former Chief Rabbi of England) translate these as **separate attributes that Hashem has given us to emulate**. The Art Scroll Siddur says that ואהבת חסד means that not only must we act with chesed, but cites the Chofetz Chaim as saying

> Hashem is not content if we merely act kindly toward others. He wants
>   us to love kindness. What someone loves to do is never a chore.

Comment: I wondered about the adjectival use, here, vs. saying *Ahava VAChesed*, making them separate attributes, which would seem to fit, here, as well. This is a nice, concise explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @DanF, IIRC some _nuschaos_ do in fact have "_Tora v'chayim, ahava vachesed_".

Comment: @msh210 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61574/759

Answer (score 2):

The Tashbetz Kattan (239) implies that at least the beginning of the line; אהבת חסד , is referring to Torah.

> בכל עת שקורין במנחה בספר תורה יש לומר בתפלת שמונה עשרה. שים שלום. לפי שיש בו תורת חיים ואהבת חסד

This is clearly implied in the Matteh Moshe's (176) presentation of the Tashbetz Kattan:

> הואיל וכתיב ביה באור פניך נתת לנו תורת חיים ואהבת חסד, שהיא התורה שקורין במנחה בשבת, וכן הוא בתשב"ץ (סי' רל"ט)

The [Rokeach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) (commentary to siddur p. 360) goes one step further and implies that that the whole line is a reference to Torah and its effects.

> ואהבת חסד וצדקה וברכה ורחמים וחיים ושלום התורה נתן לנו במאור פנים כי אהב אותנו אהבת עולם אהבתיך על כן משכתיך חסד, ונתן לנו תורת חסד על לשונה, וצדקה תהיה לנו כי נשמור לעשות, וצדקה וברכה ורחמים וחיים ושלום יהיה לנו