# Davening for Gentiles in Sim Shalom

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, kavana-intent, shalom-peace

With the invasion of Ukraine and other atrocities in the back of everyone's mind, I've been wondering if it is proper to pray for Gentiles in the bracha of sim shalom. Obviously the nusach seems to only be concerned with the welfare of Klal Yisroel, which seems to be contradictory of the ideal presented by Yeshayahu, lol yisa goy el goy cherev. I am aware that the Conservative movement has altered the nusach of the bracha to include the well-being of the entire world based on an alternative option in the siddur of Saadia Gaon. However, after looking at Rav Saadia's edition of the bracha, I am still not too convinced it was necessarily meant to include goyim, and even if it was, we nowadays do not accept that variation of the bracha. So, am I allowed to have kavana to include non-Jews even if that doesn't agree with the text? And is Judaism really not concerned with the well-being of ummot haolam? Please answer from an Orthodox perspective.

Comment: There are lots of Jews in Ukraine

Comment: In the times of the Bais Hamikdash the Korbonos on Succos were brought to bring protection and success for the gentile nations, so it’s not inherently a problem

Comment: Peace for gentiles _means_ peace for Jews as we don’t live in a vacuum. Seemingly that's what R' Saadya Gaon's text means.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61564/759

Comment: Is there any place in the amida where we pray for gentiles? Plausibly such requests just belong in a different context.

Comment: @DoubleAA Your comment about peace for Jews and goyim being related reminds me of the kabbalistic idea that Hashem's blessing goes to Yerushalayim first, then spreads from there to the rest of the world. Perhaps peace in the world comes when there is peace among Israel, relating to Chatzkel's comment, that bnei yisroel's sukkos korbanos brought atonement and success for ummot haolam. In other words, when bnei yisroel, mamleches kohanim, daven for peace and do mitzvot, acting in a peaceful manner, Hashem's blessing of peace goes down to them, and by extension to the whole world.

Comment: @vu07 That's the exact opposite of what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the true nature of the bracha of "Sim Shalom" is indeed as you have stated: to bless Am Yisrael with peace and not the entire world despite the addition of the world "ba'olam" in the Conservative variation.

However, there is a minhag in some places to daven for the welfare of the local government on Shabbos after leining, based on the words of Rabbi Chanina Sgan Hakohanim in [Avos 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.2?lang=bi). Rabbeinu Yona [comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Pirkei_Avot.3.2.2?with=all&lang=bi) that this thought ought to be extended to the entire world:

> **This matter is wanting to say that a person should pray for the peace of the whole world** and be in pain about the pain of others. And this is the way of the righteous ones, as David, peace be upon him, stated (Psalms 35:13), "As for me, when they were ill, my dress was sackcloth, I afflicted myself in fasting." As a person should not make his supplications and his requests for his needs alone, but rather to **pray for all people, that they be at peace. As with the welfare of the government, there is peace in the world.**

So it seems to me a good place to daven for the Gentile nations would be after Shabbos leining.

Comment: Shabbos is generally a bad place for extra personal requests.

Comment: @DoubleAA But Rabbeinu Yona explicitly states that davening for world peace is not a personal request as it benefits everyone.

Comment: By 'personal' I mean not in the liturgy, not affecting a single person.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was taught that the only things one can't daven for on Shabbos are health and parnassah, everything else is fine.

Comment: @Esther then why did chazal also remove the blessings for knowledge forgiveness redemption justice Jerusalem etc

Comment: @DoubleAA you still really do have a chiyuv to say those (which is why if you start a bracha by mistake you have to finish it) but they weren't required on Shabbos because it would make shemona esrei too long.

Comment: @Esther “really have a chiyuv ... but they weren’t required” that’s a paradox but anyway the same logic applies to the blessing for healing and livelihood

Comment: @DoubleAA more accurately, you *should* have a chiyuv, I gues. And if you forgot and started saying those, you would have to finish saying them as well, even though we usually don't ask for those things on Shabbos.